# Node JS / Javascript not handling error anymore

Tags: node.js

I am not sure when this started. Node JS doesn't seem to "scream" a run time error such as undefined variable, index out of bound etc.

Recently I left a typo in the code like,

```
con
var sDate = 123;
```

the server runs fine but will respond with 500 status code. After looking through the code I found "con" typo inside the code. Did I disable something by accident that NodeJS seems to stop reporting these errors?

Comment: When the function which hold your codes is NOT invoked, this error will not come up until this function is called.

Comment: Hi the thing is the function is indeed get called. I can put `console.log('Hi')` before the "con" and Hi will get printing but it will just get stuck there.

Comment: If your interested in catching these types of problems then you should enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: yes, the program get stuck caused by the `con is not defined`... If you want to check code error, [jshint](http://jshint.com/) could be one option. Or with [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: @James thank you for your suggestion. What strange is that I used to recall that these type of errors will get called out. I have been coding javascript for 1 year but recently start having this problem so I was wondering if I broke my IDE accidentally. Even with 'use strict' the error is still not thrown.

Comment: I fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: you should answer your own question rather than placing an [update]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue,

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    res.status(err.status || 500);
    next(err);
  });
}
```

I wasn't allowing NodeJS to callback to the next middleware. Initially the app will just try to render the error page right there. However, since I am using AngularJS, it does not automatically get rendered, so instead I have to use "next(err)".